# How to convert decimal values to fractions in a list of expressions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sympy, fractions

```py
import sympy as sp
from fractions import Fraction

M = sp.symbols('M')

diffs = [None, 0, 5*M/2 - 3.5, 0.5 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 1.5, 0, 1.5 - 3*M/2]

#Convert terms of expression to fractions (none of these 2 lines of code work)
diffs = [Fraction(float(val)).limit_denominator() if isinstance(val, float) else val for val in diffs]
#diffs = [sp.Rational(val).limit_denominator() if isinstance(val, float) else val for val in diffs]

print(diffs)
```

This is the output that I am getting where the terms of the expressions are written as decimals..

```py
[None, 0, 5*M/2 - 3.5, 0.5 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 1.5, 0, 1.5 - 3*M/2]
```

And this is the correct output that should be shown, indicating the terms as fractions (as long as they can be converted)

```py
[None, 0, 5*M/2 - 5/2, 1/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/ 2, 0, 3/2 - 3*M/2]
```

The truth is that I don't want it to print the terms in the results as a function with 2 parameters, for example like this `Fraction(2,3)` or `Rational(2,3)`, I need for example an output like this `2/3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> [nsimplify(i, rational=True) if i else i for i in diffs]
[None, 0, 5*M/2 - 7/2, 1/2 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 3/2, 0, 3/2 - 3*M/2]
```

Comment: Sorry, I get the same error result `[None, 0, 5*M/2 - 3.5, 0.5 - 3*M/2, -M, M/2 - 1.5, 0, 1.5 - 3*M/2]` with this code line. I don't understand how I could solve it so that it converts them to actions and can print them in the console that way

Comment: You have to re-assign to `diffs` as in `diffs = [nsimplify(...`. I was just showing you what had to be done on the rhs of the equals sign.